# Return value from javascript to html

Tags: javascript, html

```
<head>
function productName(name)
{  
}
</head>

<body>
<img src="...images/car.jpg" onclick="productName('car')">
</body>
```

What I should write in this javascript function to print the value received from the `onclick` method to any public place in my html body?

Comment: [Have you tried anything?](http://whathaveyoutried.com/)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Say you have an element like this:

```
<div id="content">

</div>
```

your js function would be like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function productName(name)
{
    document.getElementById('content').innerHTML = name;
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create a [textNode](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/DOM/Text) and append it to the body

```
function productName(name) {
    var t=document.createTextNode(name);
    document.body.appendChild(t)
}
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/DqcVd/)

Comment: Can I call the value of the name in any place in html not in js?

Answer (score 0):

Or in jQuery,

```
$('#content').html( name);    // inner HTML of an element, by ID
$('#inputField').val( name);  // into an INPUT.
```